# Setting up a custom keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to unmount/detach an external HD?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome-terminal

As there is no option to safety remove an external HD (the unmount leaves the disk still spinning), I installed `udisks`.

The following code in the terminal successfully unmounts and powers down the disk:

```
 udisks --unmount /dev/sdb1 && udisks --detach /dev/sdb
```

Since this is quite cumbersome I decided to assign it an alias; "safetyrem" which I saved into `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_aliases`.

I tried to assign a custom keyboard shortcut, `ctrl+shift+d` to execute the safetyrem alias using the code:

`gnome-terminal -e 'safetyrem'`

However, when I press the keyboard shortcut I get the error:

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal

Failed to execute child process "safetyrem" (No such file or directory)
```

The alias works if I manually open a terminal and also with the alternative `guake -e 'safetyrem'` but I'm stumped as to why it won't run on `gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bash` aliases are not real programs, `gnome-terminal` knows nothing about them and cannot execute them. Create an executable script file (for example, `/usr/bin/safetyrem`) and it should work.

BTW, the fact that the disk is spinning when you remove it does not mean the removal is unsafe. The important thing is that the system has committed all write operations and won't initiate new writes on the disk when you remove it.